# Hibernate integration with struts2 - session is null

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

I'm following this Struts2 tutorial to integrate the Struts2 project it proposes with hibernate: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_hibernate.htm
I followed the instructions step by step, the only thing I changed was the libraries, since i'm using more updated libraries.

When I try to execute my action, I'm getting a NullPointerException in my DAO class. For some reason my Session object is always null.

Here is my bean class:

```
package com.fabioSarmiento.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;
   @Column(name="last_name")
   private String lastName;
   @Column(name="first_name")
   private String firstName;
   private int marks;
   public int getId() {
    return id;
   }
   public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }
   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
   }
   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }
   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
   }
   public int getMarks() {
      return marks;
   }
   public void setMarks(int marks) {
      this.marks = marks;
   }
}
```

Here is my DAO:

```
package com.fabioSarmiento.hibernate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.SessionTarget;
import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.TransactionTarget;

public class StudentDAO {
    @SessionTarget
    Session session;
    @TransactionTarget
    Transaction transaction;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        try {
            students = session.createQuery("from student").list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return students;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        session.save(student);
    }
}
```

My hibernate config file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
   <property name="show_sql">true</property>
   <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
   <mapping class="com.fabioSarmiento.hibernate.Student" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And my struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
     <package name="myhibernate" extends="hibernate-default">
      <action name="addStudent" method="execute"
         class="com.fabioSarmiento.struts2.AddStudentAction">
         <result name="success" type="redirect">
               listStudents
         </result>
      </action>
      <action name="listStudents" method="listStudents"
         class="com.fabioSarmiento.struts2.AddStudentAction">
         <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
      </action>

</package>
</struts>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is the stack trace i'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fabioSarmiento.hibernate.StudentDAO.getStudents(StudentDAO.java:21)
    at com.fabioSarmiento.struts2.AddStudentAction.listStudents(AddStudentAction.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:873)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1539)
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:96)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:88)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1615)
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:467)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:431)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:351)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:403)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:349)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:436)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:177)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.doIntercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:88)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:105)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:253)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:155)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:120)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:174)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
    at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is this a good tutorial on how to make the integration? 
I've been researching and there's a lot of differences in the implementations i've found. But this tutorial was very useful to learn the struts part and I didn't have any issues, and now I can't finish this lesson.

How could I resolve this issue?

Thank you for your help and patience, i'm new to hibernate and i'm trying to learn on my own.

Comment: what is there in     at com.fabioSarmiento.hibernate.StudentDAO.getStudents(StudentDAO.java:21)

Comment: Hi RamPrakash, thanks for commenting the line is the following:
students = session.createQuery("from student").list();

Comment: Yes, it is null. But I'm not sure why. And I don't know how to test if my app is actually trying to connect to my db. I tried the same connection without using hibernate and it worked fine

Comment: are you using Spring to inject the dependency of session factory into your DAO?

Comment: @Will No, I'm not using any Spring libraries, the objectif was to use only hibernate and struts. Would it be better if I used Spring?

Comment: @FabioSarmientoGómez I'm just not sure how the session factory would be injected into your DAO class with hibernate config alone.

Answer (score 0):

When using createQuery, I believe the Model object class is case sensitive.

Try to change line 21 to with upper case Student:

```
students = session.createQuery("from Student").list();
```

Comment: Hi shokulei, it didn't change anything :/

Comment: Did you restart the container (Tomcat, JBoss, etc) after the code change?  Or do you have hot deployment configured?

Comment: I have hot deployment configured, but I restarted it anyways... same error.
For some reason my session object is null

Comment: Can you post your web.xml as well?

Comment: I just did :) you will find it above

Comment: While that's a typo, that certainly isn't the source of the `NullPointerException`.  The problem is that the plugin isn't injecting the session most likely, resulting the NPE.  Personally, I've never seen this plugin before and I think a more supported approach would be to use the struts2-spring bolt-on and configure a real JPA container instead.  Afaict, this plugin hasn't been updated in some time nor may be compliant with the later releases of Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Naros

Comment: I create a simple one myself and committed to https://github.com/l-tong/Struts2Example17/ .  Please try to compare the jar files in /lib/ and see if there are anything different.

Comment: @Fabio Sarmiento Gómez I added the exact same Dao, Model, and struts.xml into my example above.  And I do not have the same error you got.  I would still recommend to look at the jar files.

Comment: @shokulei that was it, thanks for your help!!
I still can't get the connection to work but at least that issue is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Ok it works now! 
I used the libraries that @shokulei provided (Link in his answer). After that I had to change my web.xml to use org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher as a filter class. Finally, I had to disable a parameter in MySQL to get SSL connection optional.
Thank you all for your help!!